# Paste RBG image without its background onto another picture (PIL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So I need to post an RGB picture (with transparent background) onto background image, but when I am trying to post it with *image.paste()* I get transparent background through which I don't see the background I want. What should I do?

Thanks!

Code (its just that):

```
        skin = Image.open("./temp2.png")
        skin = skin.resize((148, 355))
        stats.paste(skin,(42,232))

        stats.save("temp.png")
```

Images:

[Image I want to paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLYcW.png)

[The background I want to paste it on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upzSQ.png)

[Wanted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U99y.png)

[Actual Result (gray is transparent)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8d5t.png)

Comment: Can you post the original images and some code snippet?

Comment: @DNy Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [alpha composite](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.alpha_composite) in PIL to paste an image and keep the alpha channels for transparency.

```
stats = Image.open("stats.png")
skin = Image.open("skin.png")
skin = skin.resize((148, 355))
stats.alpha_composite(skin,(42,232))

stats.save("temp.png")
```

Resulting image:
[image]